# How to fix this horizontal scroll bar issue?

Tags: css

On my main Mac machine (firefox, safari and chrome) my code tags “box” renders normally:
[image]

But, on my Windows (chrome/firefox, with different screen res) it shows this empty horizontal scroll bar:
[image]

I want the scroll bar to only show up when needed, like on Mac. I'm using [this](https://github.com/htdvisser/hugo-base16-theme) Hugo theme ([live demo](https://htdvisser.github.io/hugo-base16-theme/)). Here’s my slightly modded .css (stripped of all colors and unimportant parts):

```css
/* General Page Layout */
 
body {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
}
 
.container {
  max-width: 52em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
 
div.right {
  float:right;
}
 
div.clearfix {
  overflow: auto;
}
 
@media (max-width: 52em) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
 
article.single section,
.article-list article {
  padding-left: 4rem;
  padding-right: 4rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
 
@media (max-width: 52em) {
  article.single section,
  .article-list article {
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
  }
}
 
header, footer {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
 
header {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
 
@media (max-width: 52em) {
  header {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
  }
}
 
footer {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
 
@media (max-width: 52em) {
  footer {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
 
/* Typography */
 
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.25;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
 
p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
 
h1 { font-size: 2rem }
h2 { font-size: 1.5rem }
h3 { font-size: 1.25rem }
h4 { font-size: 1rem }
h5 { font-size: .875rem }
h6 { font-size: .75rem }
 
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Input';
  src: url('/font/Input-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('/font/Input-Regular.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
 
pre, code {
  font-family: 'Input', monospace;
  font-size: inherit;
}
 
/* Homepage Layout */
 
@media (max-width: 52em) {
  .homepage {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }
}
 
.homepage h1.site-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;
}
 
@media (max-width: 52em) {
  .homepage h1.site-title {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
}
 
.homepage h1.headline {
  font-size: 3em;
}
 
@media (max-width: 52em) {
  .homepage h1.headline {
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
  }
}
 
.homepage .hero-logo img {
  width: 100%;
}
 
.homepage section.categories,
.homepage section.tags {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}
 
.homepage .tag {
  margin-right: 2em;
}
 
/* Post List Layout */
 
.article-list h1.list-title {
  font-size: 3em;
}
 
.article-list article {
  padding-top: 4rem;
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
 
.article-list article h2.headline,
.article-list article h2.headline a {
  margin-top: 0;
}
 
.article-list article .meta {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

/* Single Post Layout */
 
article.single .meta {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  text-align: right;
}
 
@media (max-width: 52em) {
  article.single .meta {
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
  }
}
 
article.single h1.headline {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 3em;
}
 
@media (max-width: 52em) {
  article.single h1.headline {
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
  }
}
 
article.single section.body {
  padding-top: 4rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
}
 
@media (max-width: 52em) {
  article.single section.body {
    padding-top: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
  }
}
 
/* Article Elements */
 
article.single * {
  max-width: 100%;
}
 
article.single pre {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 2rem;
}
 
article.single ul code, ol code, p code {
  padding: 0em 0.1em;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
 
article.single figure, article.single div.highlight {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 46rem;
  width: 46rem;
  margin-left: -1rem;
  margin-right: 0rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 0.1em;
}
 
@media (max-width: 52em) {
  article.single figure, article.single div.highlight {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to set in the .container class instead max-width: 52em and margin-left / right just: width: 50% -> (whatever percentage you'll fit and set this again for every media breakpoints) and margin: 0 auto

Comment: @lortschi
Doing that completely breaks page layout, and still doesn't fix the issue..

Comment: I tried on your demo and has worked fine to me. The main reason why you have the empty horizontal scrollbar coz your max-width set container on smaller screenresolutions couldn't be resized relatively to the page width. So best practice to use for width values percentage. And of course set this width on every breakpoints of new screenresolutions (viewports).

Comment: can you show me your code edits to achieve this, without breaking page layout?

Comment: @podstanar Instead of editing the title to "Solved", you can accept the answer that help you to fix it or it's ok to self-answer ! :) And you can't accept your own answer yet, but you will be tomorrow !

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
pre, code {
  font-family: 'Input', monospace;
  font-size: inherit;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Nope, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing `overflow-x` from `scroll` to `auto` in `article.single pre`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it happened when I set the direction attribute `rtl` in `<body>` tag,
although there's no overflow on default mode (`ltr`), however, I set the `dir` attribute for the main `div` tag under the body, like the following:

```
<body dir="rtl">
    <div>
        ... <!-- few pixels horizontal overflow -->
    </div>
</body>
```

so the worked solution for me was:

```
<body>
    <div dir="rtl">
        ... <!-- No horizontal overflow -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

It could be resolved as followed.
Please set also for all viewport breakpoints the desired width: % of the .container class.

Comment: It doesn't work, look at [this](https://i.imgur.com/LaKCoay.png) example, bars are still visible.

Comment: and also if you set body { overflow-x: hidden } ?

Comment: didn't try that because i don't want it to be hidden, sometime i will need it to actually show the scroll bar, like when some code is too wide.